# Entity Framework Code First Value Object persist to database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, code-first

I want to create Code First Entity Framework Model with some value objects. I got  exception:

> EntityType 'CustomValueObject' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

I don't want to add a key, because it isn't a full entity.

Answer (score 0):

It was enough to add annotation `[ComplexType]`to class:

```
[ComplexType]
public class CustomValueObject
{ ... }
```

Even better is to add this annotation to base class `ValueObject`, if there is one.